# Como puedo realizar un Custom post type Wordpress complejo

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Hola estoy arrancando en wordpress y estoy teniendo una duda con respecto a como encarar un proyecto que me toco, resulta que tengo que armar una sección de productos donde tengo dos tipos de productos y dentro de ellas existen categorías de este producto al que ingreso, El tema es que una ves que entro a esas categorías tendría como una especie de subcategoria de esa linea.

A modo de ejemplo yo lo vería así, supongamos que tengo como Producto + Adobe y Corel y en Adobe tendría como categoría Photoshop, Ilustraitor etc y dentro de ellas un listado de pluguin para ese respectivo programa.

Osea seria una pagina para el Programa (Adobe) donde muestra las categorias(photoshop,in design, illustraitor, etc), Una pagina con listado de Pluguin de ese programa particular y ademas una pagina de las caracterizaras de ese pluguin.

Ahora mi pregunta es como puedo encarar el armado del theme en wordpress? uso un post type general? uso varios post type?

Espero que se logre comprender mi inquietud, gracias!

Copio HTML del sitio que estoy por armar por el cual surge este inconveniente o duda
http://qkstudiodemo.com/camconnection.com/vero/1/index.html

Comment: Con la jerarquía de las propias categorías del wordpress puedes hacerlo ya que admiten abuelos, padres, hijos, nietos, etc... entonces es montar un menú con las categorías de forma normal para que cuando se haga clic, se carguen los posts de esa categoría concreta. Pero estoy seguro que no te entendí, porque eso es muy básico y si te salen problemas es que no es tan sencillo como eso. ¿Puedes explicar mejor el problema?

Comment: Si yo puse de ejemplo como de Producto de software ADOBE Y COREL por ejemplo, donde tendrían sus respectivas paginas tanto ADOBE como COREL. Cada uno tiene un listado con sus respectivos programas PHOTOSHOP/IN DESIGN/AFTER (Que serian sus categorías) etc. y Corel tendría también su categoria; COREL PHOTO PIANT/COREL CAPTURE etc, . Ahora si uno ingresa a Photoshop dentro de esa pagina hay un listado que para mi seria como una subcategoria de pluguin de ese programa. se comprende?